# TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include(). Django/python3

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error every time I try to run my app in Django. 
What's happen?
[My urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Eyz.png)

[This is my console][2]

My views.py below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect
import xml.sax
from .models import Estilo as EstiloMod
from .models import Usuario as UsuarioMod
from .models import Aparcamiento as AparcamientoMod
from .models import Comentario as ComentarioMod
from .models import Pagina as PaginaMod
from .models import Guardado as GuardadoMod
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as UserMod
# Parseadores
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler
import xml.sax
import xml.parsers.expat
import xml.sax
import urllib
```

[My urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Eyz.png)g

Comment: Can you add your views.py ?

Comment: Instead of `"aparcamientos.views.Prueba"` you should have `aparcamientos.views.Prueba` without quotes and the same for others urls.

Comment: Just done! Hope something good...

Comment: It gives me an error that aparcamientos is not defined... but it is my app's name
**NameError: name 'aparcamientos' is not defined**

Comment: You should import your app's views in urls.py like so: `from .aparcamientos import views` and in urls have for ex `url(r'prueba$', views.Prueba, name="prueba")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django 1.10 and above no longer allows you to specify views as a string (e.g. 'your_app.views.view1') in your URL patterns.

The solution is to update your urls.py to include the view callable. This means that you have to import the view in your urls.py.

You could name your urls, now for easiness.

Simple example,

```
from your_app.views import view1, view2

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^view1/$', view1, name='view1'),
    url(r'^view2/$', view2, name='view2'),
]
```

To read more about urls, [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher)

Comment: I tried putting 
`from myapp import views` 
but it takes the same error... i am not sure it is the same but i have a lot of views
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to import the view and write the url?

Comment: How can I do that exactly?

Comment: you put `from "your_app_name" import views` at the top of your urls.py file
"your_app_name" should be replaced by the name of the folder where your views.py resides..

Comment: did you add at the top, `from aparcamientos import views`?
also correct the typo, "django.views.static" as @Exprator said